# how to validate a field in tab?

Tags: validation, field

I need that the customer field is required, if it is empty when pressing  the continue button, this not must allow continue to next step and it then should appear a message indicating that the field is empty and need be completed.

Please, i need a help or advice about how to could make the validation.

Using boostrap.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" id="NotTab">
<li class="active disabledTab"><a href="#tab-customer" data-toggle="tab">1. <?php echo $tab_customer; ?></a></li>
<li class="disabled disabledTab"><a href="#tab-payment" data-toggle="tab">2. <?php echo $tab_payment; ?></a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab-customer" class="tab-pane active">
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" style="color: #F00;"><b><?php echo $entry_customer; ?></b></label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="text" name="customer" value="<?php echo $customer; ?>" class="span3" onclick="this.select();">
<input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="<?php echo $customer_id; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="customer_group_id" value="<?php echo $customer_group_id; ?>">
</div></div>
<div class="form-actions">
<button class="btn btn-primary prevtab" type="button" onclick="return showNext()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span> Next </button></div>

</div>
<script>
 var $tabs = $('#NotTab li');


function showPrev() {
    $tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').removeClass("disabled");
    $tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').find('a[data-toggle]').each(function () {
       $(this).attr("data-toggle", "tab");
    });

    $tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');

    $tabs.filter('.active').next('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').each(function () {
        $(this).attr("data-toggle", "").parent('li').addClass("disabled");        
    })
}

function showNext() {
    $tabs.filter('.active').next('li').removeClass("disabled");
    $tabs.filter('.active').next('li').find('a[data-toggle]').each(function () {
        $(this).attr("data-toggle", "tab");
    });

    $tabs.filter('.active').next('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab('show');

    $tabs.filter('.active').prev('li').find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').each(function () {
        $(this).attr("data-toggle", "").parent('li').addClass("disabled");;        
    })
}
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: there are two options: client side validation (with javascript) and server side validation (with server side language). which part are you interested in?

Comment: client side validation (with javascript) with bootstrap

Comment: check this: http://formvalidation.io/examples/enable-validator/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple check, to check if the input is empty.

```
if( !$('[name=customer]').val() ) {
    alert('Input is empty');
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank for your help, if I use a select with a name default "text-none"
It may be included in the line of bootstrap success?
<div class="success autoSlideUp"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i> <?php echo $success; ?></div>